# Pass Generic Arguments objects in Flow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I can pass types as Generic Arguments, but when I use objects containing typed parameters, Flow doesn't understand and doesn't suggest the type. Instead, I get an error.

```
export type TAction<T, R> = { +type: string, payload?: T, meta?: R };

function thisWorks(action: TAction<string, boolean>) {
  const {
    payload,
    meta,
  } = action;
  // Flow knows payload is string and meta a boolean
}

function doesntWork(action: TAction<{ prop1: string, prop2: string }, boolean>) {
      const {
        payload: { prop1, prop2 },
        meta,
      } = action;
        // Flow doesn't know the type of prop1, prop2 or meta
    }
```

The Flow error is:

> property `prop1` is missing in  `TAction` [1].Flow(InferError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the flow try to illustrate the problem described above: [Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBBAxjAlhAOwB40AaOAJQD44BeOAbzgGokUAuOAZxilwIDm5MAENEAGwgiAJgH5OZOAFtgMEfMpwAvgG4AUHoBmAVwI58BBAAtcXAOrQA1lwAUI84QXY8hIjz6C5ABGEBDiwCIEVACUjHpwcFiEPHEJCaISUtKk8WkqajkJWnRw7j4E+gkA9FVwAGKSAO5wjgQQjVxwGZIycLbcvPwCpQTSyqoipXAhYREEeloGJmblcNIQwFwEMA5Qjm4eBF6HRAwAPl1QEGAAjJz+Q8JXYABM94OCcGdawaHhkVRcglYgwgWkkgQUqC0jCumIetJOEwwM8bk9ri9tIVYQl8iJsTDivQyhZKnAwTCavUmmsNlsAOTwVrtayoNioCCGS7XNHc15waDjNRgrRAA)

From it I can see, that problem is that in the `TAction` both meta and payload are annotated as [optional properties](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties). That's why before destructuring payload it is needed to be checked, that it is not `undefined`. Code like following will not have flow errors:

```
export type TAction<T, R> = { +type: string, payload?: T, meta?: R };

function thisWorks(action: TAction<string, boolean>) {
  const {
    payload,
    meta,
  } = action;
  // Flow knows payload is string and meta a boolean
}

function doesntWork(action: TAction<{| prop1: string, prop2: string |}, boolean>
    ) {
      const {
        payload,
        meta,
      } = action;

      if (payload) {
        const  { prop1, prop2 } = payload;
        // Do whatever is needed
      }
    }
```

[Try with flow](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBBAxjAlhAOwB40AaOAJQD44BeOAbzgGokUAuOAZxilwIDm5MAENEAGwgiAJgH5OZOAFtgMEfMpwAvgG4AUHoBmAVwI58BBAAtcXAOrQA1lwAUI84QXY8hIjz6C5ABGEBDiwCIEVACUjHpwcFiEPHEJCaISUtKk8WkqajkJWnRw7j4E+gkA9FVwAGKSAO5wjgQQjVxwGZIycLbcvPwCpQTSyqoipXAhYREEeloGJmblcNIQwFwEMA5Qjm4eBF6HRAwAPl1QEGAAjJz+Q8JXYABM94OCcGdawaHhkVRcglYgwgWkkgQUqC0jCumIetkwTD8iJCrDivQyhZKnBcgBIBK4QxwFzdLIgpFwPEQlKMS7XG5Pa4vbQlMkyHGwuA1OAAEQgcEaVhEMGAADdgFA+p0CMBgNJ5ZTFjCtEA)

Or alternatively annotation for `TAction` can be changed, so `payload` and `meta` will no longer be optional properties, like following:

```
export type TAction<T, R> = { +type: string, payload: T, meta: R };

function thisWorks(action: TAction<string, boolean>) {
  const {
    payload,
    meta,
  } = action;
  // Flow knows payload is string and meta a boolean
}

function doesntWork(action: TAction<{| prop1: string, prop2: string |}, boolean>
    ) {
      const {
        payload: { prop1, prop2 },
        meta,
      } = action;

        // Flow doesn't know the type of prop1, prop2 or meta
    }
```

[Try with flow](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBBAxjAlhAOwB40AaOAJQD44BeOAbzgGokUAuOAZxilwIDm5MAENEAGwgiAJpzJwAtsBgjOFOAF8A3ACgdAMwCuBHPgIIAFri4B1aAGsuAChGnCc7HkJEefQeQAjCAhxYBECKgBKRh04OCxCHhi4uNEJKWlSWJSlFSy4jTo4Vy8CXTiAegq4ADFJAHc4ewIIeq44NMkZOGtuXn4BYoJpRWURYrggkLCCHQ09IxNSuGkIYC4CGDsoexc3Ag99ogYAHw6oCDAARk5fAeELsAAmW-7BOBONQODQ8KpsuLRBgAlIJAhJYEpKEdMRdWSMc6XK4PS5PTT5aFxXIiDFQwr0EpmcpwEFQqq1BorNYbADk8GarUsqDYqAg+kR1xRzzg0FGKhBGiAA)